# Android: What data structure to use to save app's data

Tags: java, android, data-structures

So I have a simple android app which is like this: It has a list of Car Manufacturers such as Honda, Ford, Mazda etc.
Then when one of the manufacturer is chosen, I need to display their car models. So if user selects Honda, I would display "Civic, CRV, Odyssey" etc.
And when user selects a specific model, I would display another list with more information. 
So what kinda of data structure would be simple and easy to implement in my android app. I was thinking about using nested ArrayLists.
Also, can you please provide a link to an example on how to save the data internally using android studio and get the data when I need to.

Note: The list is dynamic, meaning that the user will have the option to add or delete any item from any of lists.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered simple sqlite approach? If so, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Someone told me about that but I have no experience with any SQL related stuff; so I tough it would be very time consuming and hard to learn so I was wondering if there is any simpler solution available. If not, then I will consider sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is practically what databases are for (of course I'm talking about **SQLite** here). I'm assuming you will have loads of data that are interconnected in a way.

I do not know how well you know database design, but you should have a table called **Manufacturer** which will hold the data about those (think about what data you want to save and therefore create proper columns of the table) and a table called **CarModel** which will have a foreign key which connects it to the Manufacturer (called `manufacturer_id`). These two tables need to have **Many-To-One** relationship -> Each manufacturer can have **Many** models, but each model can be produced by only **One** manufacturer.

This is just a basic idea which you can still improve to your own liking, but this should cover everything that you asked for *very easily*. For example, to get a list of Manufacturers, you'd simply `Select * from Manufacturer`. When you click a particular manufacturer and wanna display it's models, you'd just write a quite simple query `Select * from CarModel where manufacturer_id = id` (id being the parameter you pass to some function, the `id` of the manufacturer you want the models for. The models you select can have arbitrary amount of data like additional information about that model.

If you're not that good with raw queries, there are useful [query builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) which can make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Good suggestions by @Vucko. JDXA ORM can simplify handling of one-to-one and one-to-many relationships in your domain object model. http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/mapping_one_2_many.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most approaches to implement data in Android is based on SQLite. If you don't have enough experience with it i strongly recommend to investigate following tutorials with content provider:

- [Content-provider basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)
- [Content-provider creating](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

You are right that it is very time consuming (even for experienced developers) just because this approach needs to specify entire database scheme using simple strings. But there are a few ORM-solutions you can use, such as [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml), but it still demanding task to investigate.

In addition i would reccomend [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/), that significantly simpler to implement, but, in my opinion, has many features you should consider (such as multithreading work)

Hope, it'll help.